# Preventing duplicate title entries in MKPointAnnotation array

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am making an app integrated with a map. Basically the user can put multiple map points on the map and add text to the points. I have set up the program to append to a MKPointAnnotation array every time a new point is selected. The new array entry also contains a ".title" string associated with it that is customized by the user. I am trying to add a restraint to the program that would prevent a point from being created if the user enters a ".title" that already exists (preventing duplicate names from being used.) Unfortunately other than a long hand method of calling each and every point created in the array and individually comparing them I am not sure how to do this in one go. I had a thought of doing a for loop which had a variable equal to the array.count that would determine the number of loops and also be subbed into the array spot being checked in each new loop. However for the sack of simplicity and further learning I was wondering if there is a better way to quickly compare a chosen string value with all the string values stored in each individual arrays title?

I have done my due diligence in google and youtube, forms exc.

Comment: `if annotations.contains(where: { $0.title == newTitle })`?

Comment: wow thats incredibly simplified. Thank you very much ill give it a shot. Also 10 points for rapid response time.